# Recommendations on PKI roles as per ETSI EN 319 401 - V2.3.1

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, principle-of-least-privilege

I want to configure roles (least privilege) on my CA instance (EJBCA) and I'm trying to find what are the best practices to do this.

I've tried to read the `ETSI EN 319 401 - V2.3.1` standard and try to implement this on EJBCA but it is not that obvious.

I'm thinking of implementing the following:

- **SECURITY OFFICER ROLE**

  - This role does not have a lot of things to do on the administration interface.
  - He can configure process for approving certificate generation and revocation and CA activation.
- **AUDITOR**

  - Read-Only Access
- **CA ADMINISTRATOR**

  - As the name indicates, CA administration
  - PKCS11 session
  - CRL Generation & publication
  - Certificate profiles configuration & maintenance
  - etc ...
- **RA ADMINISTRATOR**

  - Manages End Entites
  - Approve/reject End Entites certification requests (revocation requests)
  - Manages End Entities Profiles (DN, notifications to end users and other administrator, EE accounts)
  - This role can be further divided to (registration officer & revocation officer)
- **API**

  - Authorize applications to use API to generate certificates
- **Automatic Enrollment Protocoles**

  - For SCEP, CMP ... etc
- **SYSTEM ADMINISTRATOR**

  - SSH access to the CA Server
  - Technical configuration & maintenance of the CA server
  - Can use `ejbca-cli.sh`, so basically he/she can be a super administrator which defeats the whole purpose of these roles.

Is this correct ? any improvements or recommendations ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the whole exercise will depend on your business needs. You probably need to think of those first and then choose a suitable architecture, https://doc.primekey.com/ejbca/ejbca-introduction/ejbca-architecture. Regardless of your choice, here are some thoughts regarding roles.

- Security Officer, as you pointed out, is a business role so, you probably don't need a separate user group for that.
- Automatic Enrollment should be part of the API.